# Improve GoogleAppEngine Spring web application startup time

Tags: java, xml, spring, google-app-engine, spring-mvc

I have a java web application running in GAE. I use Spring for servlet dispatching. I use it so that I can use annotation to define calls in my servlet and so that it does all the parameter parsing and the result conversion. The load time for the web application in GAE is about 10 seconds and I was wondering if there's a way to shorten that. Thank you.

Here is my web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" version="2.5">


<servlet>
    <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>
                org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
            </servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>publisher-servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>
                com.example.webapp.PublisherServlet
            </servlet-class>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>publisher-servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/publisher</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml</param-value>
</context-param>

<context-param>
    <param-name>contextClass</param-name>
    <param-value>com.example.webapp.CustomXmlWebApplicationContext</param-value>
</context-param>
```

and my mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util" xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans     
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd">

<mvc:annotation-driven />

<bean class="com.y2apps.quoteformessenger.webapp.ClientController">
</bean>
```

Here is a server log of a first call which starts the server

```
I 2015-10-13 14:19:54.937  200 119.69 KB 10.98 s I 14:19:59.222 I 14:20:05.916 /getallcategorylists?typeId=2
             84.229.82.245 - - [13/Oct/2015:04:19:54 -0700] "GET /getallcategorylists?typeId=2 HTTP/1.1" 200 122562 - "okhttp/2.2.0" "iron-core-93812.appspot.com" ms=10978 cpu_ms=13017 cpm_usd=0.01369737 instance=00c61b117c057f572d9967e34ef8e65bb7cbfdcd app_engine_release=1.9.27 trace_id=-
I 14:19:59.222 javax.servlet.ServletContext log: Initializing Spring FrameworkServlet 'mvc-dispatcher'
I 14:20:05.916 This request caused a new process to be started for your application, and thus caused your application code to be loaded for the first time. This request may thus take longer and use more CPU than a typical request for your application.
```

Comment: Have you considered a [Warmup Request](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/config/appconfig?hl=en#Java_Warmup_requests)? It doesn't shorten the load time, but hides it: "Warmup requests load application code into a new instance before any live requests reach that instance."

Comment: Assuming that you also have a `COntextLoaderListener` stop loading your beans twice.

Comment: Startup on app engine takes a while depending on luck / load and spring itself isn't the fastest either, especially if you make it do lots of automagic things like class path scanning. The less dynamic you make it, the faster it should get. You can test that locally.

Comment: Thank you Andy. I replied to Patrice below why this doesn't solve my problem.

Comment: Thank you  M. Deinum. What do you mean by that? How am I loading the beans twice?

Comment: Thank you zapl. I avoided class path scanning and I define my controller directly.

Answer (score 1):

I tried everything and couldn't shorten the 10 seconds startup. I decided that it's too important for me, so I removed spring from my server and cut down startup time from 10 seconds to 4-5 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by [Andy Turner](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3788176/andy-turner), your best bet to skip that long startup time is [Warmup Requests](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/config/appconfig?hl=en#Java_Warmup_requests), which will... well, "warmup" your instance, and pre-loads certain things that need to be loaded, meaning that your instance will be "ready to hit the ground running" when the first request comes in.

The other suggestions (not to load your beans twice and minimize class path scanning) will definitely help as well. There's not much you can do besides these three suggestions.

Comment: thank you Patrice, the problem is my web application serves a mobile app and the first request it send takes the 10 seconds. The thing is I don't know in advance that the user will open the app. I can send these requests all the time but that just means that I'll keep the server running all the time which will cost money (and I can do that without the fake requests).

Comment: @yaronbic then maybe changing your scaling to keep a min idle instance of 1 could work? or.... I know python (and go) have almost NO load time when compared to java.... probably not good for you as you don't want to change your whole application, but depending how far along you are, might be a solution

Comment: Thanks Patrice. Yeah I won't build it from scratch now, but I didn't know that about python, perhaps I'll use it in the next one. Thank you